# Powershell new-aduser attribute was not in the acceptable range

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue with the following Powershell script. It is

a value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of values Line 1 char 59

`Import-Csv .\tableofusers.csv | foreach-object {New-ADUser -Path "ou=ou,dc=dc" -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -Name $_.name -DisplayName $_.name -GivenName $_.gn -SurName $_.sn -StreetAddress $_.SA -city $_.city -state $_.state -PostalCode $_.PostalCode -Country $_.Country -officephone $_.officephone -emailaddress $_.emailaddress  -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -force) -enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false -Passthru}`

I have been over it many times I cannot see the issue in or arround on character 59
any help would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was country that was the problem, it took a bit but I was able to comment out most of the block until I found that $_.Country did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your piped variable token is wrong, it should be $_ rather than $ ie:

`Import-Csv .\tableofusers.csv | foreach-object {New-ADUser -Path "ou=ou,dc=dc" -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -Name $_.name -DisplayName $_.name -GivenName $_.gn -SurName $_.sn -StreetAddress $_.SA -city $_.city -state $_.state -PostalCode $_.PostalCode -Country $_.Country -officephone $_.officephone -emailaddress $_.emailaddress -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1" -AsPlainText -force) -enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false -Passthru}`

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at my script and I did have the $_. for each variable, for some reason when I pasted the script it did not include it,

Comment: Are any users from your spreadsheet imported ok? Replace {New-ADUser  
with 
{write-host $_.SamAccountName; New-ADUser

This will write the SamAccountName of each user you import and help you spot which line is causing a problem.

Comment: Thanks, no users are being created I tried your suggestion and the lines look correct, the error  line number is directly after the new-aduser

Comment: Ah ha, it was country that was the problem, it took a bit but I was able to comment out most of the block until I found that Country did not work

Answer (score 0):

At a guess the value given to -country in the CSV file was something like United Kingdom instead of the code for the country which is GB.

You can look up a country code by setting the country/region in AD on the address page using the drop down list.  Then whilst you have Advanced Features turned on (View>Advanced Features) open the user and on the Attribute Editor tab look look for the value of attribute c to see the code for the country you've set.  Put that country code into the CSV file and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was using initials with more than 6 characters. Using dots between the initials means that > 6 is already reached when the initials are "A.B.C."